# ordering hibernate query by with select

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, subquery, hql

Is it possible to write hql query to order by some subquery?
There's query like this:

```
select a from A.a join a.b where a.b.id = :id
```

what I need is something like:

```
select a from A.a join a.b where a.b.id = :id order by (select count(c) from C c where c.a = a.id) desc
```

Comment: As per my knowledge ordering is done on the columns in the table forming the select. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: if I use native query it works, but I can't find how to do with hql. So maybe you are right and it's possible only when you have direct relation (count, avg etc should work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My aliasing system does not seem to be working. Or it may be a bug with hibernate, but this thing works(though very inefficient) and I have to hard code the alias

```
SELECT a, (SELECT COUNT(c) FROM C c WHERE c.a = a.id) AS col_1_0_ 
FROM A.a 
JOIN a.b 
WHERE a.b.id = :id 
ORDER BY col_1_0_
```

I am using Hibernate 3 and MySQL

Comment: You may need to watch the hibernate sql generated for this hql to determine the alias.

Comment: As I don't think that there's better way (or maybe other way) to do what I asked, I accepted this as an answer (even I don't think it's good to have such in production, but that's another discussion).

Comment: Alias problem has been fixed in Hibernate 3.6.0 RC2 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1902